# To sum up the inputted value of StockQuantity from StockInTbl into ProductQuantity from ProductTbl in Mysql using C#

Tags: c#, sql-server

I just want to sum up the value from StockQuantity from StockInTbl into ProductQuantity from ProductTbl in Mysql using c#. Below is my code where I get the value inputted from the ProductTbl to be revealed on a grid table. The following code is where I get the value inputted from the StockinTbl to reveal on the other grid table. I also have my table definition of StockInTbl and ProductTbl below.

```
//Product
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into ProductTbl values('" + ProductIdTb.Text + "', '" + ProductNameTb.Text + "', '" + ProductQtyTb.Text + "', '" + ProductPriceTb.Text + "', '" + ProductDescTb.Text + "', '" + VarietyCombo.SelectedValue.ToString() + "')", Con);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    MessageBox.Show("Rice product Successfully Added");
    Con.Close();
    populate();
}
```

```
//StockIn
private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (BatchIdTb.Text == "" || SupplierNameTb.Text == "" || VarietyCombo.SelectedValue.ToString() == "" || StockQty.Text == "" || 
        StockInDate.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss") == "")
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please Fill-in the Text Boxt Above");
    } else {
        Con.Open();
        string input = StockQty.ToString();
        int stock = 0;
        int StockInQty;
        if (int.TryParse(input, out StockInQty)) {
        } else {

        }
        int newQuantity = stock + StockInQty;
        string query = "update tb1.ProductQuantity = tb2.StockQuantity + '" + newQuantity + "' from ProductTbl tb1 join ProductTbl tb2 on tb1.ProductID = tb2.BatchID where tb1.ProductID = BatchID";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into StockInTbl values('" + BatchIdTb.Text + "', '" + SupplierNameTb.Text + "', '" + VarietyCombo.SelectedValue.ToString() + "', '" + StockQty.Text + "', '" + StockInDate.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss") + "')", Con);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        MessageBox.Show("Rice Stock Successfully Added");
        Con.Close();
        populate();
    }
}
```

I am unsure about this line of code in

```
string query = "update tb1.ProductQuantity = tb2.StockQuantity + '" + newQuantity + "' from ProductTbl tb1 join ProductTbl tb2 on tb1.ProductID = tb2.BatchID where tb1.ProductID = BatchID";
```

And where to put the needed code for my desired output on StockIn or Product.

Comment: What is not clear for you? Does the code compile? Does it run? Are you getting any error? Can you share the error details?

Comment: @Chetan I don't get any error sir, but when I run it does not get my desire output